# Mockito ArgumentCaptor is null

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, mockito

I'm a beginner, please bear with me. :)

Scenario:
JUnit testing with Mockito on IntelliJ / Maven.
I'm trying to read a passed parameter with an ArgumentCaptor in Java. The problem is, this captor itself is null. The captor does not seem to work at all.

```
@Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Invoice> cap; 
    ...        
        verify(invoiceDao).insert(cap.capture());
```

I suspect the problem is, that I cannot use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) due to other reasons. (I have some stubs placed in a @BeforeEach method and it throws me UnnecessaryStubbingExceptions.)

Is there a way to use th ArgumentCaptor without @ExtendWith? Or is this not the cause for my problem in the first place?

I'm sorry if I am totally lost here. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the `@Captor` annotation only works when you enable the MockitoExtension.

But you can also manually initialize the ArgumentCaptor without the `@Captor` annotation:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Xxx> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Xxx.class);
```

Or, if you just need to avoid the UnnecessaryStubbingExceptions, you can add `@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)` above the `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` annotation, and keep using @Captor/@Mock.

Comment: Thanks mate. I think that was the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

`@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` is not required to use `@Captor` with JUnit4. This is a JUnit5 feature and I am still using JUnit4.

For me the use of `@Capture` annotation failed as you described as well as the  `ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Invoice.class)`

Unfortunately the class I was trying to capture had methods that were final and it seems Mockito was just returning null...
I needed to rework how I tested to avoid the class with the final.